# Showing that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) = \infty$, then also $m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \infty$ for a difference measure $m$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and $l_1, l_2$ be measures on $S$ such that $\forall A \in S:l_1(A) \leq l_2(A)$. Define the mapping $m:S\to [0, \infty]$ by $m(A) = \sup\{l_2(A') - l_1(A')\mid l_1(A') < \infty \land A' \subset A \land A' \in S\}$. I am trying to show that $m$ is a measure. I have already verified that $m(\varnothing) = 0$ and I am currently trying to show that $m$ satisfies $m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n)$ for a disjoint sequence of elements $A_1,A_2,\dots$ of $S$.

So far I have argued that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) < \infty$ then it follows from the definition of supremum (and letting $\epsilon$ tend to zero) that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) \leq  m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$. But I am unable to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) = \infty \implies m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \infty$ due to the fact that I would have to separate the two measures $l_1, l_2$ into two separate sums and I don't seem to have any tools to prevent $\infty - \infty$ case. Namely if $m(A_n) < l_2(A_n') - l_1(A_n') + \epsilon 2^{-n}$ then $\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (l_2(A_n') - l_1(A_n') + \epsilon 2^{-n})$. And from here I would somehow need to separate the two measures into their own sums to arrive at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n) \leq m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$.

All tips and hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is $m(A_i)=\infty$, then $m(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\ge m(A_i)=\infty$. Otherwise, we have $l_1(A_n)\le l_2(A_n)<\infty$, and we may use your strategy but more carefully handle the infinity. For any $M>0$, we may find $N>0$ and $A_1'\subset A_1, \cdots, A_n'\subset A_n$ such that $$M<\sum_{n=1}^N l_2(A_n') - l_1(A_n')=l_2(\cup_{n=1}^N A_n') - l_1(\cup_{n=1}^N A_n')\le m(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) $$

By working with $N$ instead of $\infty$, we can avoid $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l_1(A_n')=\infty$, which led to $\infty-\infty$ as you mentioned.

Comment: Of course, it's nothing but the definition of a divergent limit. Is there a clean way to argue about the monotonicity of $m$? A priori we know only that $m$ is defined as the supremum difference between two measures s.t. $\infty - \infty$ does not occur.

Comment: All maths is nothing but definitions... I don't know but I have doubts. Intuitively, $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ has infinite $m$-measure, because the difference between $l_2$ and $l_1$ can be made as large as possible, but not through a single difference being infinity, and the filtration $A_1\subset A_1\cup A_2\subset A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$ provides a sequence of differences that go to $\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure w.r.t. what you have doubts but regarding my earlier comment: The monotonicity of $m$ follows immediately by taking $A_1 \subset A_2$ and $B \subset A_1 \subset A_2$ s.t. $l_1(B) < \infty$ with $m(A_1) \leq l_2(B) - l_1(B) + \epsilon \leq m(A_2) + \epsilon$.

Comment: OK. Monotonicity is trivial: If $A_1\subset A_2$, then the subsets $A'$ we take to define $m(A_1)$ is also part of the $A'$'s used to define $m(A_2)$, so you don't need $\epsilon$ for it. Now if you have shown the additivity holds for finite sums, then $\sum_{n=1}^N m(A_n)=m(\cup_{n=1}^N A_n)\le m(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$, and let $N$ goes to $\infty$, we're done.